# List archived teams

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

Is it possible to list archived teams without querying each /teams/{teamId} endpoint?

I can get a list of teams by calling for instance https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/joinedTeams, and then for each team I get back I can check the IsArchived property.
As far as I'm aware of there is no endpoint that returns a team list that also supports OData querys.

Similar question to this posted in the GitHub Graph Docs:
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/6406

Regards,
Oskar

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no graph API to list archived teams. we recommend you to raise a Teams UserVoice [here](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/) if this needs to be consider as a future request.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if it's possible to get this status without going to /teams/teamId?
The reason I'm asking is because it seems that if I go to /education/classes/{classId}/group/team I'm actually going to /teams/{teamId} in the background.  I'm trying to get around the 30rps limit that is on /teams/{teamId}

Comment: @OskarJenssonFjeld - Currently there is no workaround other than this.

Comment: It would be best if /classes/{classId} would give me this property as well :)